# Are there irreducible multi-fusion categories that are not fusion categories?

Tags: fusion-categories, unitary-fusion-category

Multi-fusion categories are a generalization of fusion categories with a non-simple unit. The direct sum of two multi-fusion categories is again a multi-fusion category. By irreducible I mean that a multi-fusion category cannot be written as a non-trivial direct sum. Are all such irreducible multi-fusion categories fusion categories?

Bonus question: Are there multi-fusion categories that are not Morita equivalent to a direct sum of fusion categories?

[I'm mainly interested in the unitary case.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Matrix categories, $\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{Vec}^{\oplus n})$.  (The identity on each copy of $\mathrm{Vec}$ are summands of the identity.)

(You can generalize this example by putting fusion categories along the diagonal of a matrix, and Morita equivalences between them into the off-diagonal entries.  Over an algebraically closed field irreducible multifusion categories examples look like this, which you can see by decomposing the multifusion category as a module over itself.)

Comment: Is the implicit (sub)text of this answer "Matrix categories *are irreducible multi-fusion categories that are not fusion categories*"?

Comment: Indeed, matrix categories are irreducible multi-fusion categories that are not fusion categories. They cannot be written as direct sums of other multi-fusion categories.

Comment: Oh, right of course. I wanted to answer the physics question "are there non-symmetry-breaking topological phases arising from multi-fusion categories that go beyond the Levin-Wen/Turaev-Viro model for fusion categories?", but your answer shows that what I asked is not equivalent to this, as your matrix-category example is still a trivial phase.

Comment: I added a bonus question that I hope corresponds to the actual physics question I would like to answer...

Comment: Assuming the base field is C (weird issues arise if it's not algebraically closed), I'm pretty sure any multifusion category is Morita equivalent to a fusion category.  Take $1_i$ to be a summand of $1$, and look at the category of $1_i$-modules.  This gives a Morita equivalence between your original category and the *fusion* category of $1_i$-bimodules.  This is a rephrasing of my parenthetical.

Comment: Ok thanks! But shouldn't it rather be "any *irreducible* multifusion category is Morita equivalent to a fusion category"? Because a direct sum of fusion categories can never be Morita equivalent to a fusion category. Or am I confusing something here?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  This indicates you need to be a little careful with my proof sketch, which is roughly right but you need to be careful about the category of $1_i$-modules being a *faithful* module category which doesn't happen if the original category is reducible.